# R - Rename ID names of a spatial object

Tags: r, polygon, spatial

My goal is to change the ID names of a SpatialPolygon object. I know how to access the ID names but I'm stuck to rename them.

Here is an example (it's a SpatialPolygonDataFrame but in my 'real' case it's a SpatialPolygon, so without the necessary link between polygons and the data frame) :

```
library(rgdal)
library(rgeos)
library(sp)
library(maptools)

data(wrld_simpl)
mymap.sp <- wrld_simpl[which(wrld_simpl$ISO3 == "ATG" |
                             wrld_simpl$ISO3 == "BRA" |
                             wrld_simpl$ISO3 == "FRA" |
                             wrld_simpl$ISO3 == "CIV"), ]

# access to the ID names
sapply(slot(mymap.sp, "polygons"), function(x) slot(x, "ID"))
[1] "ATG" "BRA" "FRA" "CIV"
```

Suppose I want to replace these ID names by "1", "2", "3", "4".

Comment: what do you want to change the names to?

Comment: I have completed my post to answer your question.

Comment: `Warning message: In data(wrld_simpl) : data set ‘wrld_simpl’ not found`

Comment: @Nate `wrld_simpl` is in the `maptools` package.

Comment: Sorry for forgetting `maptools`, I corrected the post again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If performance is not an issue, you can do this in a `for` loop:

```
new_IDs = paste0("ID", 1:4)
for (i in 1:length(slot(mymap.sp, "polygons"))){
  slot(slot(mymap.sp, "polygons")[[i]], "ID") = new_IDs[i]
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm cleaning up a really messed up polygondataframe and this helped me a bit.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using the `sp::spChFIDs` function instead of rolling your own loop. Specifically, you could change your IDs like this:

```
new_ids <- as.character(seq_len(nrow(mymap.sp)))
mymap.sp <- sp::spChFIDs(mymap.sp, new_ids)
```

Comment: I agree - your method works well. For the sake of generalisation, I would suggest changing the last part to ...as.character(1:length(mymap.sp)) rather than hardcoding.